# Home directory in two locations taking double space on disk?

Tags: linux-mint, disk-usage

So the issue started when thunderbird tried to compact emails but failed and prompted that not enough disk space. That was weird message since my linux mint is installed on 64GB ssd.
So I did a disk usage analysis and found that my home directory is accounted twice. Once in media/... and the other time just as home
[image: disk usage analysis results w/ two home folders]

The disk usage for both is 12.2GB, out of which 7.5GB is thunderbird. So it seems that 7.5GB of my emails are stored twice.

Anybody know why this is? How to get it so that my stuff would be stored only once?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like some kind of ”live Linux with persistence”-type setup.

If that is true, then most of your actual root filesystem is a virtual union of two things: a) a read-only system image and b) a filesystem that contains just the additions/replacements you’ve done since starting to use the system.

In a new system the /home directory is initially essentially empty, and so the actual contents of your home directory would be completely in b).

I would guess that your /home is a virtual representation of a) + b), and the `/media/kaspar/casper-rw/upper` is the real storage for b) only.

To confirm this, the output of the `lsblk` command would be helpful.

If my assumption is correct, your home directory data is not actually stored twice: it jusl looks that way because the virtual a)+b) construct cannot overlap and hide the real b) filesystem, because the driver that builds the virtual image needs to see both the source filesystems it builds the composite out of.